# error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'const C4::C4TrackKey' and 'const C4::C4TrackKey')

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Can't seem to wrap my head around this error I am receiving:

```
namespace C4
{
  struct STA
  {
    C4::C4TrackKey track_key;
    C4::C4TrackNumber  track_number;

  bool operator==(const STA &rhs) const
  {
    bool is_equal = false;
    if(this->track_key == rhs.track_key &&
       this->track_number == rhs.track_number)
    {
      is_equal = true;
    }
    return is_equal;
  };
```

> error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'const
>   namespace::struct' and 'const namespace::struct')

The operand types are the same and the other comparisons are compiling just fine.

Comment: I hope you don't actually have a type named `struct`...

Comment: Sorry, I don't. Just for privacy measures but I can see how that is confusing. I'll go ahead and edit the post.

Comment: You should show us the comparison of `C4TrackKey`, not `STA` (judging from your title).

Comment: Presumably the problem is in the way you defined `operator==` for `C4TrackKey`.